# Python - Reversing original value after encoding

Tags: python, pandas

Let's say I have the following dataframe.

df_original

````
```
ID    Code    Score     Level
1     Q1       0       Low
2     Q2       11      Low
3     Q3       100     High
4     Q4       50      Medium
5     Q5      1000     High
6     Q6      122000   High
```
````

I would like encode scores >100 to 100 and keep the rest as it is.

````
```
df_original['EncodedScore'] = ''
scores = {0.0:0,  11.0:0, 100.0:100, 50.0:50, 1000.0:100, 122000:100}
df_original['EncodedScore'] = df_original['Score'].map(scores)
```
````

I got the following.

````
```
ID    Code    Score     EncodedScore   Level
1     Q1       0          0           Low
2     Q2       11         0           Low
3     Q3       100        100         High
4     Q4       50         50          Medium
5     Q5      1000        100         High
6     Q6      122000      100         High
```
````

I would like to create pivot table out of this based `ID, Code, and EncodedScore`.

#Pivot table for EncodedScore

```
df_pivot= (
    df_original.reset_index().pivot_table(index = "ID",
                   columns = "Code",
                   values = "EncodedScore", aggfunc=max, dropna=False)
)
```

I got this pivot table based on the encoded score value.

df_pivot1

```
ID   Q1   Q2   Q3    Q4     Q5       Q6 
1    0    
2         0
3             100        
4                    50     
5                            100       
6                                     100
```

My question is at this level replacing the `EncodedScore` value with the `Score` value. I would like to get the following table back with original `Score` value.

df_pivot2

```
ID   Q1   Q2   Q3    Q4     Q5       Q6 
1    0    
2         11
3             100        
4                    50     
5                            1000       
6                                     122000
```

Can any one help on this?

Comment: What's wrong with reusing `pivot_table` and changing `values = "EncodedScore"` to `values = "Score"`?

Comment: Re clipping the score, use `df.Score.clip(upper=100)`.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
new_df = df.drop(['Level'], axis=1).pivot(columns='Code', index='ID').fillna('').droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)
```

Output:

```
>>> new_df
     Q1    Q2     Q3    Q4      Q5        Q6
ID                                          
1   0.0                                     
2        11.0                               
3              100.0                        
4                     50.0                  
5                           1000.0          
6                                   122000.0
```

Comment: Hey, this ```df``` is df_pivot1 or df_pivot2?

Comment: `df` is `df_original`, here.

Comment: For some reason it is saying ```ValueError: Index contains duplicate entries, cannot reshape ```

Comment: Try this: `df.drop(['Level', 'ID'], axis=1).pivot(columns='Code').fillna('').droplevel(0, axis=1).rename_axis(None, axis=1)`

Comment: I got the same error.

Comment: Is your real DF very different from the sample one? Can you provide a few rows with `print(df.head(5).to_dict())`?